# can port of a cq instance be set in terminal

Tags: aem

their is an option for setting run mode of a CQ Instance directly in terminal
viz `-Dsling.run.modes=${CQ_RUNMODE}`
is their a similar option for changing the port as well.
I'm basically looking for a solution to keep changing name of CQ jar for a new instance.
Thanks

Comment: **Apache Felix Jetty Based Http Service** OSGi configuration also can be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**-p** option can be used to set the port number from command line.

Ex:  `java -jar cq5-4502.jar -p 4503` will start the instance on 4503 even though the jar name contains 4502 as the port number.

Comment: properties supported by Sling can be found here: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/the-sling-launchpad.html and here: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html

Comment: And the -h option lists supported options.